# How do you save the redirect URL of a link in Cypress

Tags: cypress, http-redirect

I have a link that I need to click which redirects to a different URL. I have used cy.request and saved the response. I can see the redirect URL in the response when using cy.log, but don't know how to get just the URL by itself. Here's my Cypress code:

```
cy.get('#myElement')
.then(function ($a) {
  const href = $a.prop('href')
  cy.request('POST', href).then(function (response) {
    cy.log(response)
  })
})
```

Below is the response as seen in the browser's console. There are 3 places that I can get the URL from as indicated by the red boxes. The bottom one looks like it would be the most ideal place to get it from because it's the least nested, but I would then need to trim the '302' from the start of it:

[image]

Comment: Can you add an example of all of the censored information? (possibly just omitting the baseURL?) It will be to helpful to see how they are the same or differ.

Comment: you can use response.headers.location, that way you will get the URL without the need to parse the response body or trim any unwanted characters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The screenshot looks like it's the network tab of dev-tools.

If so, I think the following will give you the value (but you may need to examine the result of `console.log()` and vary the breakdown I give below a little bit)

- `redirects` looks like it's a property of response, and it's an array so index it with `[0]` (since you want the first, perhaps it is the only one)
- the result of that is a string, and you can split off the `302` by dividing at the `:` char
- the result of the split is an array, and you want the 2nd part so use `[1]` index

```js
cy.request('POST', href)
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response)       // easier to work with console.log than cy.log

    // detailed breakdown
    const redirects = response.redirects
    const firstRedirect = redirects[0]
    const redirectKeyAndValue = firstRedirect.split(':')
    const [statusCode, URL] = redirectKeyAndValue
    cosnt redirectUrl = URL


    // or all in one line
    const redirectUrl = response.redirects[0].split(':')[1]
  })
```